# Problems with data binding listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

All of a sudden have an issue with a listbox binding that I did not have before.

I've got a ViewModel in which I have two observablecollections with some data in it. Both lists are populated correctly.

In the MainPage() constructor

```
DataContext = App.ViewModel;
InitializeComponent();
```

The lists in ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Saloon> Saloons { get { return ... } set { ... } }
public ObservableCollection<TTSaloon> TTList { get { return ... } set { ... } }
```

I am binding the first list to a map control and are able to get the pushpins bound to the "Location" property that is in the list.

```
<my:Map DataContext="{Binding Saloons}"....> 
<my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}"/>...</my:Map>
```

The above works fine. But I also do have a listbox that should be bound to the other collection(TTList) like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TTList}" DataContext="{Binding}" Name="listBox1">
                  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" Foreground="White" />
                             </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

But this does not work at all. I have tried alot of different things:

- Setting the ItemSource in code-behind
- Removing the DataContext from the ListBox
- Changed the Binding Path to Listname.Property
- Setting the DataContexts on the elements to the specific list in code-behind.
- Setting the DataContext after InitializeComponent()

I am out of ideas, what am I missing here, the debugger is not warning me either. 
The field "CustomerName" does exist and is printed to the console.

Edit: it's a pivot app and the listbox is in pivotitem two if that could have an impact.

Comment: How are you populating the TTList?

Comment: It's populated from a webservice, a json response that gets serialized to a class. The two lists are populated in the same way just from different sources.

Comment: Do I need to set the DataContext after the data has been received and list has been populated? When I am binding the pushpins that is not necessary thouh

Comment: CustomerName needs to be a public property, is that the case?

Comment: Yes it is. Tried to bind the listbox to the Saloon list(which the pushpins are bound to without any problems) and that did not work either. Now I am even more confused. The Saloon list are accepted as the datacontext for the map but not as a itemsource for the listbox.

Comment: Try removing the `ItemTemplate` - you should get the text of the type of the item in each list (including the namespace). Do you get it? Also, try removing the setter for `DataContext`

Answer (score 0):

Yout foregound is set to white. Maybe you just can't see the items because of white letters on white background?

Comment: Hehe I did that mistake once, but the background is black now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you raising OnPropertyChanged when the ObservableCollection is "set" a value?

(ObservableCollection only raises changes by itself when doing an "Add", "Remove" or "Clear")

Comment: Yes, but there is something else happening here. When I moved the methods that I use to populate the collection and the collection itself to MainPage.cs file it works if I set the ItemSource when OpenReadCompleted. Strange thing is that I was not able to bind the Saloon list(which is already bound to the map) to the listbox.